# Cakephp TCPDF error: TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: cakephp, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I have installed TCPDF following instructions on below link:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf

However when I put this through controller, I am getting below error:
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I cannot seem to figure out why. I've tried search through view files to ensure there are no spaces before any PHP tags. I'm out of choices...

Is there anything that I could check?

I think I know where the error is coming from. Below is the code for where the error is getting outputted in tcpdf.php:

```
case 'D': {
                // download PDF as file
                if (ob_get_contents()) {
                    $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
                }
```

Comment: if (ob_get_contents()) var_dump(ob_get_contents())

Comment: I'm now getting this error: string(2) " " TCPDF ERROR: string(2) " "

Comment: This means there is a space getting echoed somewhere but what debugging can I do to find this bugger??

Comment: I found a temp solution by using 'S' instead of 'D' in the view file reason being there seem to be issue with 'D' case. I had a look at what comments had to say about this article (link above) but there are quite a bit of codes that have not been introduced in the original article such as "__view" function which is writer's 'hidden' function. For people struggling, use this instead "echo $tcpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'S');" I will find where space is getting outputted in case 'D' and write a new comment soon. Thanks deizel, I also got a bit interested in Lithium since I'm a Cake fan! Hehe. :D

Comment: Also ensure to use your own __view function. I used view instead...

Answer (score 4):

you just add ob_end_clean() above the switch statement.thats it..it will clear the header

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean output buffer by using `ob_clean()`

*or*

Avoid printing spaces or any variable before outputting PDF content

Answer (score 0):

Also remove the line

```
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
```

from your code if you added it in.

P.S. The ob_clean() works well for me if I put it in the 2nd last line of the Output public function as mentioned by rajapandian and Kamil Ilyas:

```
public function Output($name='doc.pdf', $dest='I') {
    //LOTS OF CODE HERE....}
    }
           ob_end_clean(); //add this line here 
    return '';
}
```